# Delete 'Run Anything' history in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 2019.3 and I want to delete "execute maven goal" in Run Anything history. How can I do that?

All the answers I found was to delete workspace.xml but that does not work for this version.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This information is indeed stored in `.idea/workspace.xml` file inside the project:

```xml
  <component name="RunAnythingCache">
    <option name="myCommands">
      ...
    </option>
  </component>
```

Note that workspace file can be relocated to IntelliJ IDEA **system directory** in the Maven based project if you have the option to [store generated project files externally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVnw9.png) enabled.

In this case, you will find the workspace file here:

[idea.system.path](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)`\workspace\<project_name>.<hash>.xml`

When modifying these files, make sure IDE is not running or the project is closed.

Answer (score 31):

One other way of deleting it, is selecting it by going to it with your cursor keys, then press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>. This does not require editing the `workspace.xml`

Comment: This is the correct answer!