# intellij-idea how to delete a custom Run Maven Goal in context menu?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I added a maven goal command through [context menu]->[Run maven]->[New Goal], but i typed wrongly and i want to remove it from the menu.

I cannot find out how to remove it even if I looked up the idea help document.

my new custom goal screenshot

[image: my new custom goal screenshot]

Thank you!

Comment: Should be doable from the [Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html)

Comment: @thinkgruen i still find nowhere to remove it..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ + Execute Maven Goal: How to delete from recent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610298/intellij-execute-maven-goal-how-to-delete-from-recent)

Comment: It looks like you're using Maven Helper plugin. You can remove the goal from Settings/Preferences | Other Settings | Maven Helper | Goals.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov It help! I didnt realize the context menu is come from Maven Helper plugin and i thought that is a idea native function.. your comment should be an answer,Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using Maven Helper plugin. You can remove the goal from `Settings / Preferences | Other Settings | Maven Helper | Goals`.